# Code in VBA excel remove and replace

Tags: vba, excel

I have two excel sheets. One is an estimate and one is an invoice. I have them set up so that whatever I type in the estimate is also populated into the invoice. There are some words that need to be changed to past tense. For instance, on the estimate form it will say "Remove x" and on the invoice it also says "Remove x". I would like to know if it's possible to have the invoice automatically change "Remove x" to "Removed x"? I tried using these two solutions I found online:

`Worksheets("sMain").Columns("D").Replace _
What:="Avenue", Replacement:="Ave.", _
SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=True`

and

`ary = Array("Remove")
For Each wd In ary
    Columns("AT").Replace What:=wd, Replacement:="Removed", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=True
Next`

But I get a compile error: invalid outside procedure. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Put the code in a subroutine.

Answer (score 1):

Running this a macro will automatically find and replace in the column.

First: I created a list of sample data.

```
this is a test to find and replace.
I want to visit Canada
Renee likes to go to Mexico
Mexico is south of the border
Have you ever been to united states of america?
Canada
Mexico
United States
Mexico
```

Second: I created a list of 2 columns for what I wanted to find and replace.

```
Find            Replace
Canada          CAN
Mexico          MEX
United States   USA
Mexico          MEX
```

Third: Create and run the macro.
    Sub MultiFindNReplace()
        Dim Rng As Range
        Dim InputRng As Range, ReplaceRng As Range
        Set InputRng = Application.Selection
        Set InputRng = Application.InputBox("Original Range ", "Search Range", InputRng.Address, Type:=8)
        Set ReplaceRng = Application.InputBox("Replace Range :", "Find and Replace Range", Type:=8)
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        For Each Rng In ReplaceRng.Columns(1).Cells
            InputRng.Replace what:=Rng.Value, replacement:=Rng.Offset(0, 1).Value, Lookat:=xlPart
        Next
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End Sub

Comment: If this answer (or another) was helpful, would you Vote on it and Accept it.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

Lets start with some basic code; Open Developer, select Visual Basic, and paste this code in ThisWorkbook
If your Invoice worksheet is not named "Invoice" change it to reflect your sheets name.

```
Sub Replace()
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Invoice").Columns("AT")
    .Replace What:="Remove", Replacement:="Removed", lookat:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Risk with this solution is that if there is a loop anywhere, the word "Removed" includes the word "Remove", so could end up with "Removedd" or "Removeddd". This is not a problem with the code example above, but something to be wary of for the code that calls this code.

Comment: @ADJ, Thanks for the input, when helping an individual with minimal vba experience, I try to give keep the code as easy to understand as possible. When someone ask a question starting with "I’m new to vba", or they just provide a piece of code they have copied off the internet, providing a perfect solution, in my opinion, is not helping them learn at their experience level. It will also allow them to ask another question if they run into the possible issues you identified.